# How to pass parameters to NUnit Test Cases through the UI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

Is there any third-party UI tool to accept and pass parameters to NUnit Test Cases?
    I am desperately looking for it.
    Your comment and suggestion are much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, you could prompt with a simple winforms dialog for some text from the [Setup] method before each test.  I'm not sure however you would be able to work out which test was being run at this point. You would also need to take care re-threading as nunit 2.4 will not run tests using UI capable threads (STAThreads).

Far better would be to load test configuration data from an input file during [SetupFixture]

Comment: .. Thanks for your explanation .. how about NUnit 2.5?

Comment: You can do it more easily in 2.5 i think by decorating your method with [STAThread]

Comment: Thanks. I put the winforms dialog at the first line of the test cases and somehow it is working so far.

Answer (score 1):

I was using [Interaction.InputBox Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: .. Thanks for you suggestion but I am using C# and is there any other way to create dynamic dialog based on the parameters required.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [TestCaseSource attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5.9)

You can pass data in test even from file or a collection of items.

Comment: .. :) ... I am using TestCaseSource attribute and searching how to integrate UI Dialog to accept user inputs ..

Comment: @Kyaw - you could code up a method to read inputs off a CSV file using the TestCaseSource attribute. Then use Excel as a GUI to edit the CSV OR write a custom WPF/Winforms GUI to create the CSV input files and then invoke nunit.

Comment: Gishu is right, that I mean when I said to use TestCaseAttribute